# Expected to do a boolean evaluation, but then it become a value of returning

Tags: javascript

In my react project

I have three data:

data.leverageSelected,  (type: boolean)

data['leverageRate'] (type:number)

data['loanAmount'] (type:number)

Below is my code,

I want to check if **data.leverageSelected** is true, then get the result of true/false evaluation of data['leverageRate'] , data['loanAmount']

For example,
as long as **data['leverageRate']** or **data['loanAmount']** hold some values, then it means the condition is true, go to line 10

if **data.leverageSelected** is false , if means the evalution is true,as the condidtion become false, and true is assigned, then go to line 12

```
if (
      (data.leverageSelected ? data['leverageRate'] || data['loanAmount'] : true)
   
    ) {
      return false  <---line 10
    } else {
      return true <----line 12
    }
```

Q: but now it always only goes to line 12, when I assigned some value in  **data['leverageRate']** or **data['loanAmount']** .

It doesn't work as my expected output

To better illustrate my problem, below is a example

```
const a = 4

const b = 2

console.log(a && b) <--- 2
2
console.log(a || b) <----4  but I want it return true to me, rather than value of a, which is 4. 

If I am able to achieve this, I could change previous code
```

Comment: `then get the result of true/false evaluation of data['leverageRate'] , data['loanAmount']` what?

Comment: but I want to keep it in one line and see if it can be done in one line, and I dont know why it doesnt do like boolean evalution as other lanaguage

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  leverageSelected: true,
  leverageRate: 10,
  loanAmount: 20
}

if (data.leverageSelected && (data['leverageRate'] || data['loanAmount'])) {
  console.log(false) // <---line 10
} else {
  console.log(true) // <----line 12
}
```

Comment: How do I make if data.leverageSelected is false , return me a true in this ？　
For example, I also have a value called amount to check. like const data = {
  leverageSelected: true,
  leverageRate: 10,
  loanAmount: 20,
  amount: 20
}

the value of leverageSelected only matters for leverageRate or loanAmount, when leverageSelected is true, then I need to check both value; when leverageSelected is false, I expected it the statement become true and , together with the amount value( if it has amount in it) then return false at the end

Comment: It works as in your description @AeLeung